# PowerShell copy random files

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am trying to copy 7 random `.txt` files to a different location, but sub-folders get copied instead of the `.txt` files.

Here is my script:

```
$d = @(gci G:\Users\Public\Test) | resolve-path |  get-random -count 2 
$d | gci | get-random -count 7 
Copy-Item $d  -destination G:\Users\Public\Videos
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution might be to use the PSIsContainer attribute to filter out folders.
I tried the following...

```
$d = gci "C:\Work\a\*.txt" | Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $false}| resolve-path  |  get-random -count 7
Copy-Item $d  -destination C:\Work\b
```

The where clause filtered out anything that was not a "container" and ignored the test folders I had set up. If you need .txt files specifically then use the wildcard included in the path as above.

Also, if you were to add -recurse then it would presumably search in all sub folders of your original search location and still filter out any "folders" for copying. Though I haven't tested this very thoroughly.

```
$d = gci "C:\Work\a\*.txt" -recurse | Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $false}| resolve-path  |  get-random -count 7
```